# How to retrieve mails that were send in test mode

Tags: mailgun

Hey I am trying to use Mailgun as E-Mail Service Provider. For testing I have the requirement to retrieve and check test mails.

Is there a possibility to get the payload and all attachments of a mail that was send in test mode? I could not find any documentation for that except https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-in-test-mode
I am using this command to send test mails:

```
curl -s --user 'api:$API_KEY'  https://api.mailgun.net/v3/$DOMAIN/messages \
-F from='Excited User <mailgun@$DOMAIN>' \
-F to=$TEST_MAIL \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
-F o:testmode='True'
```